# OneDrive application keeps vanishing from my harddrive

Tags: applications, ms-office, error, microsoft, onedrive

I'm not sure if this is an issue with OneDrive or MacOS... but the OneDrive app keeps disappearing from my Applications folder.

On one occasion, my whole OneDrive folder had '(Archive)' added to the end of its name.

I can reinstall the app but then it is gone again after I've restarted my Mac.

I've never known anything quite like it.

I also posted on the MS forum but couldn't get an answer, I also found a Reddit post of someone who had a similar issue of MS applications disappearing on Mac

Comment: Have you tried to log out of the existing account and then log back in? (use the existing folder)

Comment: Have you installed OneDrive from the Mac App Store or from an installer downloaded from the Microsoft website? What is the model / year of your Mac? Which version of macOS is your Mac running?